# How to get all automationelement in screenshot in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, automation, screenshot, ui-automation

I create a wpf application which takes and shows a screenshot of the monitor. And I wanna get all automation elements in the screenshot, so I call findall() with TreeScope_Children. But it returns elements of all windows in the monitor, not the windows on the desktop when taking screenshot. If I want to find elements in screenshot. How should I set the condition?

```
private Condition ChildrenCondition = new NotCondition(new PropertyCondition(
                                         WindowPattern.WindowVisualStateProperty,
                                         WindowVisualState.Minimized));
AutomationElementCollection ac = topElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, ChildrenCondition);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a library beyond UIA or MSAA, you can record one element or one window, then can get children or iterate sibling elements. clicknium.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ClickCorp.clicknium